# Use jQuery with <select> option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, radio-button

I found a jQuery code which allows me to check id a certain radio/checkbox is checked, and then show something else based on the selection.  Is there a way to do this with a `<select>` option?  For instance, if I have a select box that has "Bread", "Milk", and "water" as the options, and the user clicks "bread", it would show "BREAD is $2.99", but if you select "Milk", it'll say "MILK is 2.49".  The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/U9Jsh/.

Thank You.

Comment: I think you'd have to learn programming yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  You can use the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler on the select and $(this).val() in the handler.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwDVd/) for an example that shows changing based on bread and milk.  It's a small self-contained example not based off of your fiddle that should get you started.  You can also use the "[option:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)" selector.

Comment: This is probably a more elegant solution than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

use $('select option:selected') to get the currently selected option or options (if it is a multiselect).

Comment: +1 Exactly. OP could've found this information with a quick Google search.